# My Python code for logistic regression gradient for Andrew Ng course does not work

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I have written some code for the non-regularized logistic regression cost function and for finding a gradient but no matter what I try, my code keeps returning the same TypeError.

I have already tried a vectorized and for-loop implementation of my code and nothing has been working. I would also like to point out that the grader always grades my cost function with full marks but not the code for finding the partial derivatives. My results always match the expected cost, but nothing is returned for the gradient part.

It says that this is the Cost:
J()=1∑=1[−()log(ℎ(()))−(1−())log(1−ℎ(()))]

And this is the Partial Derivative:
∂()∂=1∑=1(ℎ(())−())()

(From doing the course, I can verify that this is correct)

```py
def costFunction(theta, X, y):
    # Initialize some useful values
    m = y.size  # number of training examples

    # You need to return the following variables correctly 
    J = 0
    grad = np.zeros(theta.shape)

    # ====================== YOUR CODE HERE ============
    for i in range(m):
        hypothesis = sigmoid(np.dot(theta.T, X[i, :]))
        J += y[i] * math.log(hypothesis) + (1 - y[i]) * math.log(1 - hypothesis)
        for j in range(n):
            grad = (hypothesis - y[i]) * X[i, j]

    J = (-1 / m) * J
    grad = (1 / m) * grad
    # =============================================================
    return J, grad



# Initialize fitting parameters
initial_theta = np.zeros(n+1)

cost, grad = costFunction(initial_theta, X, y)

print('Cost at initial theta (zeros): {:.3f}'.format(cost))
print('Expected cost (approx): 0.693\n')

print('Gradient at initial theta (zeros):')
#print('\t[{:.4f}, {:.4f}, {:.4f}]'.format(*grad))
print('Expected gradients (approx):\n\t[-0.1000, -12.0092, -11.2628]\n')

# Compute and display cost and gradient with non-zero theta
test_theta = np.array([-24, 0.2, 0.2])
cost, grad = costFunction(test_theta, X, y)

print('Cost at test theta: {:.3f}'.format(*cost))
print('Expected cost (approx): 0.218\n')

print('Gradient at test theta:')
print('\t[{:.3f}, {:.3f}, {:.3f}]'.format(*grad))
print('Expected gradients (approx):\n\t[0.043, 2.566, 2.647]')
```

I expect the output to be:

```py
Cost at initial theta (zeros): 0.693
Expected cost (approx): 0.693

Gradient at initial theta (zeros):
    [-0.1000, -12.0092, -11.2628]
Expected gradients (approx):
    [-0.1000, -12.0092, -11.2628]
```

but instead I get the following:

```py
Cost at initial theta (zeros): 0.693
Expected cost (approx): 0.693

Gradient at initial theta (zeros):
Expected gradients (approx):
    [-0.1000, -12.0092, -11.2628]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-ab2a7b541269> in <module>()
     15 cost, grad = costFunction(test_theta, X, y)
     16 
---> 17 print('Cost at test theta: {:.3f}'.format(*cost))
     18 print('Expected cost (approx): 0.218\n')
     19 

TypeError: format() argument after * must be an iterable, not numpy.float64
```

Comment: it doesn't work. Although it does successfully remove most of the errata, my marks haven't changed (Cost: 30/30 | Gradient: 0/30), and my gradient function still doesn't return ANYTHING for the grad variable. I really appreciate your help but I can't find a way to progress without this. If anyone can help me I would be extremely grateful. 

Answer (score 1):

When looking at the function `costFunction()`, the return value `J` (which you are assigning to `cost`) is a scalar. Therefore, it cannot be unpacked with a star `*` and should be passed directly to the string formatting method:

```
print('Cost at test theta: {:.3f}'.format(cost)) # passing 'cost' without the star
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this out and see if the grader grades it correctly. I would also like to say that the code that is written here (except for the function) is not my own. It is part of the assignment. This means that there might have been a mistake or a better way to do this. Once again, thanks for your helpful reply and have a nice day :).                                                          Here is the link that I used for my assignments: https://github.com/dibgerge/ml-coursera-python-assignments